# Android System Icons Semi-Transparent

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

By default `android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete` is semi-transparent so that the color of the action bar will show through the icon.

[image]

If I wanted the `ic_menu_delete` icon to be solid white to match my other icons, is there a way to do this other than image editing software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a CustomDrawable that would draw stuff without the transparency but it sounds to me way more work than head over to [android asset studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) select the icon and download.

Comment: I'm a little lost on how to use this site to solve my problem. I have gone to the site and selected `Action bar and tab icons` and proceeded to choose the semi-transparent image from my machine as the source. Next I Choose a custom color of white at 100%. However, after downloading the zip, the images are still semi-transparent.

Comment: I guess that site only proper do colors on their own clipart set. But, their own clipart set is the same default Android icons. For sure you you'll find `android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete` there.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the clip art option the first time around. That actually worked perfectly. Great answer.